# Accessing a variable inside a function for calculation

Tags: python, function, permutation, replicate

I am trying to access a variable from inside a function and its giving me an error which says:

```
NameError: name 'perm_sample_1' is not defined
```

Code is here:

```
def permutation_sample(data1,data2):
    data = np.concatenate((data1,data2))
    permuted_data = np.random.permutation(data)
    perm_sample_1 = permuted_data[:len(data1)]
    perm_sample_2 = permuted_data[len(data1):]
    return perm_sample_1 , perm_sample_2
    #return perm_sample_1.shape ,perm_sample_2.shape

def draw_perm_reps_func_diff(data1,data2,func,size=1):
    perm_replicates = np.empty(size)
    for i in range(size):
        perm_sample_1 , perm_sample_2 = permutation_sample(data1,data2)
        perm_replicates[i] = func(perm_sample_1) - func(perm_sample_2)
    return perm_replicates

stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1=np.mean(perm_sample_1), std1=np.std(perm_sample_1), nobs1=len(perm_sample_1),mean2=np.mean(perm_sample_2), std2=np.std(perm_sample_2), nobs2=len(perm_sample_2))
```

Comment: Unless declared `global` in the function beforehand, variables within one are _local_ by default and cannot be referenced outside of it. You can return the value and the caller can then use it to do things (instead of using global variables which is generally considered a poor programming practice). It looks like you're doing that, because your question doesn't show the full traceback which would indicate where the `NameError` is occurring.

Comment: Thanks @martineau
So how can I run the calculation at the end which references the variable used inside the function?

Comment: `how can I` - Add a parameter to the function and pass it when calling the function.

Comment: Since you haven't shown where `draw_perm_reps_func_diff()` being called and how it relates to the last line, I have no idea.

Comment: link to code:
https://easyupload.io/mqgxkb

Comment: `NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-69-b6d0de005a93> in <module> ----> 1 stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1=np.mean(perm_sample_1), std1=np.std(perm_sample_1), nobs1=len(perm_sample_1), 2 mean2=np.mean(perm_sample_2), std2=np.std(perm_sample_2), nobs2=len(perm_sample_2)) NameError: name 'perm_sample_1' is not defined `

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error is thrown in the last line (please provide the a meaningful stack trace in the future):

the variable `perm_sample_1` is out of scope for the function call. You've to define it outside of the function to be able to access it.

One way would be to return it in `draw_perm_reps_func_diff(...)` addition to the other value. Although, there are prettier solutions to this.

Comment: I tried the following:

```
def draw_perm_reps_func_diff(data1,data2,func,size=1):
    perm_replicates = np.empty(size)
    for i in range(size):
        perm_sample_1 , perm_sample_2 = permutation_sample(data1,data2)
        perm_replicates[i] = func(perm_sample_1) - func(perm_sample_2)
return perm_sample_1
return perm_sample_2    
return perm_replicates

```

this does not work. it says perm_sample_1 not defined

Comment: `NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-69-b6d0de005a93> in <module> ----> 1 stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1=np.mean(perm_sample_1), std1=np.std(perm_sample_1), nobs1=len(perm_sample_1), 2 mean2=np.mean(perm_sample_2), std2=np.std(perm_sample_2), nobs2=len(perm_sample_2)) NameError: name 'perm_sample_1' is not defined `

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do was run the function calling the variable outside the function

```
def func(a,b):
    c = a+b 
    d = b+5
    return c , d

z , y = func(12,5)

e =  z*2
f =  y/5
```

I should get 
e = 34
f = 2